# HTML form submit button is not vertically centered

Tags: html, css, forms, submit

This is my first time posting, so I hope I'm doing this right.

I want to style a search bar [like this one](http://speckyboy.com/2012/02/15/how-to-build-a-stylish-css3-search-box/)

The problem is, the submit button is always a little off vertically in comparison to the text-input. No matter what I do, there is always at least 1px offset. Help is MUCH appreciated!

I have the following code:

```css
.searchfield{
 -webkit-appearance:none;
 border: 3px solid #1a5087;
 border-right: 0px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 height: 30px;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 outline: 0;
 display: inline;
}

.searchbutton{
 -webkit-appearance:none;
 background-color: #ffb800;
 height: 36px;
 border: 3px solid #ffb800;
 width: 40px;
 color: white; 
 margin-left: -25px;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: 0;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position: 2px 2px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 display: inline;
}
```

```html
<form action="action.php" method="post">
  <input type="number" name="name" placeholder="placeholder" required class="searchfield">
  <input type="submit" value="search" class="searchbutton">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried relative positioning on the submit button?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to rebuilt the same in fiddle. Have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/LrqL2f03/)

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search here..." required>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of CSS changes should fix the alignment:

- Add `vertical-align: middle;` to both `.searchfield` and `.searchbutton` to align them to the middle of each other
- Add `padding: 0;` to `.searchfield` to remove any padding that the browser may apply to it by default
- Remove `margin-top: 5px;` from `.searchbutton` to stop it from being pushed down

```css
.searchfield{
 -webkit-appearance:none;
 border: 3px solid #1a5087;
 border-right: 0px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 height: 30px;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 outline: 0;
 display: inline;
 padding: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.searchbutton{
 -webkit-appearance:none;
 background-color: #ffb800;
 height: 36px;
 border: 3px solid #ffb800;
 width: 40px;
 color: white; 
 margin-left: -25px;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: 0;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position: 2px 2px;
 /*margin-top: 5px;*/
 display: inline;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <input type="number" name="name" placeholder="placeholder" required class="searchfield">
 <input type="submit" value="search" class="searchbutton">
</form>
```